# Symfony3 AJAX request from iframe on the same domain does not save Session attribute

Tags: php, ajax, session, symfony

I use Symfony v3.0.6 on PHP 5.5.28 with OPcache Enabled.
Security for site administrators is managed by FOSUserBundle.

Site users visit a page where they are displayed a non Symfony form in an iframe from the same domain which makes an AJAX request to simple Symfony action:

```
public function validateAction(MailingList $mailingList, Request $request)
{
  $email = $request->get('email');
  $code = $request->get('code');
  if ($mailingList->getCode() == $code) {
    $response = new Response('', 200);
    $securityManager = $this->get('security_manager');
    $securityManager->grantAccess($request->getSession(), $mailingList, $email);
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return $response;
  }
  $responseFailed = new Response('N2', 401);
  $responseFailed->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  return $responseFailed;
}
```

As you can see i call my custom service SecurityManager where i add an attribute to the Session:

```
public function grantAccess(Session $session, MailingList $mailingList, $email) {
  $session->set('page_'.$mailingList->getId(), 
    json_encode(array(
      0 => hash('sha256', $email.$mailingList->getCode()),
      1 => $email
    ))
  );
}
```

The AJAX call succeeds and the whole page is reloaded with `window.reload()`

After the reload Symfony debug toolbar does not show any signs of attribute set in the previous Request.
I have also tried to use Cookies, but with no success. The same pattern remains.

Comment: I wonder if you need to call `getSession()` on some other controller page like so: `$session = $request->getSession();`. I know I had to do this on all of my controllers when I was using session variables. This may not be the solution, but you can check. I moved away from using session variables, and instead now use routing parameters because a lot less coding is needed and it 'looks' cleaner.

Comment: `getSession` is called everytime i need to work with it. It looks like the problem itself lies in that iframe and main page have separate sessions and i did not find a way to share something between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved and the short lesson - **do not use iframes or frames. ever.**

`<iframe>` and the main page have separate PHP sessions (checked the session IDs). So the buggy process looks like that:

1. AJAX request is sent from `<iframe>`
2. Symfony action updates attributes in `<iframe>` Session
3. Response 200 comes back and JavaScript reloads the whole page (`window.reload()`).
4. On page load main page Session gets checked for token and obviously there is none there, so the login form gets displayed.

**Important note!**

Some older browsers or new browsers, but with less strict security/privacy settings may use the same session for the main page and `<iframe>`.

This was the main reason why it took so long for me to hunt that bug down. It looked like the code behaves inconsistently.

After dropping the use of `>iframe>` the code worked like a charm.

Thanks everyone for your ideas. Hope this saves some time for other fellow programmers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Symfony 3.1 and able to save session information via ajax.

May be, you should inject `@session` as service argument instead of passing as a parameter to the method in your service.

Comment: I will try this solution. Got loggers everywhere, so It seems that the session is updated with the new parameter in the validate action, but on page reload new parameter is not there anymore.

Comment: Nothing changed. As far as i can see there are 2 separate sessions in my main page and in iframe which has the form. Both are in the same domain.